# Does web push notification body need to be escaped?

Tags: javascript, browser, push-notification, xss, web-push

Following [Using the Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API), I can display a push notification successfully.
Some of my push notifications contain user-entered text (like the user's name for example).

Do I need to escape the [Notification.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/body) from special characters before passing it to the push notification? Or is it safe to pass it any string unescaped?

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, the body of a Notification is a [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) which is interpreted as UTF-16, the same as what `String` handles. Assuming what you are trying to render is available in UTF-16, you should only need to escape quotes.